Might students using ChatGPT to learn languages develop a kind of "ChatGPT accent"?
Students (like me) who use ChatGPT for second-language learning may pick up some of ChatGPT's idiosyncrasies.  E.g., ChatGPT changes my 很多 to 许多, and I've kind of adopted this into my writing style.  And every list of examples has 3 items; no more, no less.
I'm wondering if there are any case studies which describe this (if it exists), or even just teacher anecdotes where they have noticed ChatGPT-isms in their students' language output (speaking or writing).
Question: Might students using ChatGPT to learn languages develop a kind of "ChatGPT accent"?
I didn't immediately find a relevant paper by searching for ChatGPT language idiosyncrasies in Google Scholar.
